# How do the document object model values filled by last changed values?

Tags: javascript, dom

while studying the DOM  , i wrote the below script :

```js
console.log(document);//how this will generate the last update id value
var x = document.getElementById("old").getAttribute("id");
var y = document.getElementById("old").setAttribute("id","IDChanged");
console.log(document);
```

```html
<div id="old">first</div>
```

both of results are  :

```
<div id="IDChanged"><div>
```

after running this snippet, i found that both of the results are generating the html document with the same id which is the `IDCHANGED` , and what I expect is that the first console.log will generate a document with div , its id is `old` and the second `console.log` will generate the document with the `div` id is `IDChanged`.

SO, HOW to do this work?

Comment: `console.log()` does not "generate" anything. It returns a string to the `console` for you to see. It does not alter the DOM in any way.

Comment: In modern browsers, when you output an object like the `document`, the console will show you the *current* value, rather than the value at the moment it was logged.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  : i didn't say that the console.log change anything, i just used it to dump the output only.

Comment: @Sidney : when the script reaches the console.log edge, it will save the values of the document at this time and to be dumped out.

Comment: Yes, you did. You said the results are "generating the html document". The results are the `console.log()` statements and they do not generate anything. In fact, none of your code "generates" anything. The `setAttribute()` line simply modifies the value of the `id` attribute.

Comment: @ScottMarcus : i know that the setAttribute did that and i have no objection to it. i have an objection to the idea of how do both of console.log will generate the div with the same id which is the last updated value.

Comment: Again, `console.log()` does not generate anything. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the `document` object (for some reason that makes no sense), when you are really more interested in the `div` element. I don't know why you say that you see `IDChanged` logged twice when neither of your `console.log()` statements would produce that at all, they would both log the `document` object, not the `div`.

If you get rid of your first `console.log()` and change the last one to:

```
console.log(x,y);
```

you will see the results you wanted., but really, forget about `document` and focus on the `div`. I think this is what you are looking for to see the `id` before and after the changes.

```js
// Get a refernece to the div
var x = document.querySelector("div");

// Report the contents of the document before doing anything:
console.log(x);

// Change the ID of the element
x.setAttribute("id","IDChanged");

// Report the contents of the document after DOM manipulation:
console.log(x);
```

```html
<div id="old">first</div>
```

Comment: i know that the console.log is logging the documet itself not the div , but this div is included in the document. so if really the value changed after using the setAttribute function , the first console must log the document including the div with the initial value and the last console will log the document including the div with the updated IDChanged value.

Comment: @youhana No, you are misunderstanding what is outputted by `console.log(document)` - you aren't going to see the `div` shown in either case. You will only see properties of the `document` and their values. The `div` is not a property of the `document` and you won't see it in either `console.log()`. But, if you logged the actual `div` found within the `document`, you would. I will update my answer to show this.

Comment: @youhana Do you understand now? Do you see that no where in the output of `console.log(document)` will you find the `div` included in the results (run the code snippet I added to your question to see what you do get from that)?